# What Does "State Sponsored" Cyber Attacks Mean?

Tags: attacks, government, apt

I am hearing on [the news](http://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/cyber-attacks-canada-cse-1.4378711) this morning that a government of country "A" found tens of thousands of instances of "state sponsored attacks" against it's information systems.

What is meant by "state sponsored" attacks in this case? I assume it to mean attacks which were either originated from or were carried out on the requests of some foreign country's government. How exactly can security analysts know an attack is "state sponsored"?